# Switch from default python interpreter to ipython in elpy (Django command)

Tags: django, emacs, ipython, elpy

Elpy uses the default python interpreter (elpy-django-command shell), I wondered if it is possible to use Ipython instead.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. See the elpy docs on [interactive-python](https://elpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ide.html#interactive-python). Set

```lisp
(setq python-shell-interpreter "ipython"
      python-shell-interpreter-args "-i --simple-prompt")
```